# Check integral for convergence

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

For the given integral check whether it converges/diverges:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{\operatorname{arctg}(\alpha x)-\operatorname{arctg}(\beta x)}{x}dx}$$

Literally have no ideas how to cope with it, have tried to estimate $\operatorname{tg}^{-1}(x)$ as $x$, however with no result.

Comment: What a bizarre an unnecessarily confusing way to write arctangent.

Comment: @EricTowers, fixed that, it is quite common in my college actually, but that seems strange to me to, especially when trying to write arc in some degree.

Comment: @EricTowers: $\operatorname{arctg}$ is the old notation (used by Bourbaki, for instance).

Comment: @Bernard : You might want to look at the *first* version of the question.

Comment: Do you have any assumptions on the signs of $\alpha$ and $\beta\mkern2mu$?

Comment: @Bernard, not at all..

Comment: @MarkViola Thank you! I was wrong indeed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We initially assume that both $\alpha>0$ and $\beta>0$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_\varepsilon^L \frac{\arctan(\alpha x)-\arctan(\beta x)}{x}\,dx&=\int_\varepsilon^L \frac{\arctan(\alpha x)}{x}\,dx-\int_\varepsilon^L \frac{\arctan(\beta x)}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{\alpha \varepsilon}^{\alpha L}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}\,dx-\int_{\beta \varepsilon}^{\beta L}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{\alpha \varepsilon}^{\beta \varepsilon}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}\,dx-\int_{\alpha L}^{\beta L}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_\alpha^\beta \frac{\arctan(\varepsilon x)-\arctan(Lx)}{x}\,dx
\end{align}$$

Letting $\varepsilon\to 0$ and $L\to \infty$ we find that for $\alpha>0$ and $\beta>0$

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(\alpha x)-\arctan(\beta x)}{x}\,dx=\frac\pi2 \log\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)$$

If both $\alpha<0$ and $\beta<0$, then we have

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(\alpha x)-\arctan(\beta x)}{x}\,dx=-\frac\pi2 \log\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)$$

The integral diverges if $\alpha \beta<0$.

Comment: And why does integral diverges if $\alpha \beta < 0$?

Comment: @James Assume that $\alpha>0$ and $\beta<0$.  Then, $\arctan(\beta x)=-\arctan(|\beta|x)$.  Now, what happens?

Comment: both arcs sum up?

Comment: And can you show that $\int_1^\infty \frac{\arctan(\alpha x)}x\,dx$ fails to converge when $\alpha\ne0$?

Comment: Not actually...

Comment: Since $\arctan(\alpha x)$ is increasing on $[1,\infty)$, $\frac{\arctan(\alpha x)}{x}\ge \frac{\arctan(\alpha)}{x}$.  Now what can you conclude?

Comment: Sorry, have no internet connection during these days. divergence seem straightforward to me now, thanks for all your explanations.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

For convergence or divergence on the $\infty$ side, you may think of using the  relations
$$\arctan x+\arctan\frac 1x=\begin{cases}\phantom{-}\frac\pi 2&\text{if }x>0,\\[1ex]-\frac\pi 2&\text{if }x<0. \end{cases}$$
This will lead you to obtain an asymptotic equivalent of the integrand, which will depend on the signs of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

*Some details*:

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have the same sign, say positive, we have
$$\arctan \alpha x =\frac \pi 2 -\arctan\frac1{\alpha x}=\frac\pi 2-\frac1{\alpha x}+o\Bigl(\frac1x\Bigr)$$
by Taylor's formula at order $1$. Similarly
$$\arctan \beta x =\frac\pi 2-\frac1{\beta x}+o\Bigl(\frac1x\Bigr),$$
so that we obtain
$$\arctan \alpha x-\arctan \beta x =\frac1{\beta x}-\frac1{\alpha x}+o\Bigl(\frac1x\Bigr),$$
which means that
$$\arctan \alpha x-\arctan \beta x\sim_\infty\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha\beta }\frac1{x}\quad\text{if }\alpha\ne\beta,$$
and consequently
$$\frac{\arctan \alpha x-\arctan \beta x}{x}\sim_\infty\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha\beta }\frac1{x^2},$$
which has a convergent integral on the $\infty$ side.

Can you examine the other cases?

Comment: May you please explain more about asymptotic equivalent..

Comment: Did you never see equivalent functions, the notations $o$ and $O$ ?

Comment: Maybe you could also utilize more explicit $\arctan u-\arctan v=\arctan\frac{u-v}{1+uv}$

Comment: Ok, thanks, got it!